# Adding custom js files in AMP html?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, amp-html

I want to add custom javascript plugins, like owl-carousel in my AMP pages is it possible to do so?

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not insert an external javascript in AMP because AMP does not javascript. But using amp-iframe you can create the functionality in the `iframe` and include that iframe in AMP page.

So if you want to display images using owl-carousel, make an iframe in which you have implemented image carousel using owl-carousel and include that iframe in your AMP page. So it will look like it is on AMP page only. So iframe will contain image tag with owl-carousel.

However, if you want to display images in the carousel in AMP pages, visit https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-carousel
This will help you anyway to implement image carousel in AMP.

If you specify your requirements then I can help you to design your iframe or amp-carousel, whichever is possible.

Comment: I got the idea about amp-iframe. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

AMP pages do not support **custom/external** scripts to be loaded in the page header. It doesn't even allow to load external `stylesheets`.

You can refer their official docs [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec#html-tags). That states

> Scripts are Prohibited unless the type is application/ld+json. (Other non-executable values may be added as needed.) An exception is the mandatory script tag to load the AMP runtime and the script tags to load extended components

Comment: I've gone through many sites and I found that we have to use <amp-iframe> to include external js, and I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add custom js script in AMP, Instead of Javascript its better to use AMP components. AMP have its own carousel [amp-carousel](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-carousel/)

Example : [Click Here](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-carousel%2Fsource%2F)